# APT always suggests removing NVIDIA driver

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.2 and just settled in as I decided to finally switch from Windows, for good.

But then I started having problems on Linux, where APT would automatically suggest removal of NVIDIA drivers.

Even after I installed them it would suggest that *they're not used* or *required*.

I don't very often run **apt autoremove** but I like to keep things simple and always clean up the unnecessary.

If there's a way to blacklist certain packages from being recognized by autoremove or anything similar to that, please let me know because it makes no sense for my graphics driver to get removed, how is it *not being used* is my question.

Thanks!

Comment: you should just be able to `apt install` the modules it reckons are no longer required.  it's only suggesting that the modules are to be `autoremove`d because they have no installed modules that have them as a dependency

Comment: @Jad Interesting, so I should just ignore its message, its not mandatory to autoremove (I guess?)

Comment: possibly, but I do use `autoremove`, to get rid of old kernels, so it might be best just doing an `apt install` on the drivers you've got, unless it's letting you autoremove these ones because there are newer versions installed

Comment: @Jad I went in and did `autoremove` and `purge` of all nvidia related packages, rebooted and reinstalled the same drivers through apt, with all of its dependencies like nvidia-compute, nvidia-settings, etc. and now it works fine, no more NVIDIA related packages in autoremove. So I'm guessing there was some collision with the files or cache, I don't know I'm new to Linux and learning, but that's how I solved it (hopefully for the long run.) Thanks for your time and help, much appreciation!

Comment: This seems to be a potential general issue of the Ubuntu installer with NVidia cards - I just freshly installed 22.04 on a PC with an NVidia card (and selected to install proprietary drivers during install); and now apt tells me that basically all "*nvidia*" packages "no longer required"...

Answer (score 3):

I did `autoremove` and `purge` of `*nvidia*` packages, rebooted the system and reinstalled the same drivers again and rebooted.

No more NVIDIA packages in the autoremove list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sudo apt-mark manual <package1> <package2>
```

Packages explicitely installed with `sudo apt install` are marked as "manual".

If needed, the reverse operation of "manual" is "auto". For more details, see the [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/apt-mark.8.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have been affected by a very similar issue after a fresh install of XUbuntu 22.04 on a PC with an NVidia card. I selected to install proprietary drivers during install; After the installation finished, `apt` told me that basically all "nvidia" packages were "no longer required"

Also, the "Additional Drivers" application showed an option "manually installed driver", and didn't let me select another option.

What seems to have fixed it for me was a manual installation of the nvidia driver version that apt reported was "not required":

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
```

Seems to me like there's something botched in the Ubuntu installer when choosing the proprietary drivers option.